# DOCTYPE stops my div from showing

Tags: css, html, doctype

I have the following code which, as expected, shows a grey rectangle in both Firefox and IE. As soon as I add a DOCTYPE (HTML 4.01 Transitional) in front, it shows only a blank page. The online validator says the document is OK. What is wrong? Should I care about DOCTYPE?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
   #gallery
    {
      width:750;
      height:548;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the units for your width and height. I assume you're going for pixels so:

```
#gallery
{
  width: 750px;
  height: 548px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: A Doctype declaration doesn't always trigger Standards mode, see http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#handling

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I rolled back my answer. Thanks for the link - completely forgot about almost standards mode!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified the units of measure for the height and width attributes in your CSS. Without a DOCTYPE the browser will attempt to render the page as best it can (QUIRKS mode), in your case I think it probably guessed the correct units. By adding the DOCTYPE you have told the browser to follow a very specific set of instructions when rendering the page - no guessing that you wanted pixels instead of percents.

Comment: That makes sense, but I thought Transitional triggers quirks mode anyway in most browsers. Or this hybrid mode (Transitional) vs. quirks mode (no `DOCTYPE`).

Comment: @Lèse. It's a bit more complicated than that. See http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#handling for a thorough explanation.

Comment: I don't think a Transitional DOCTYPE is the same as quirks mode i.e. it still has rules based on the Standards, where as no DOCTYPE is entirely up to the browser vendor. I think it is coincidence that some quirks match the Transitional rules.

Comment: @Lèse and Dan – The full HTML 4.01 Transitional Doctype (`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`) triggers ‘Almost standards mode’ in most browsers. See http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#handling

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS was buggy.

```
  width:750px;   /*  PX!! */
  height:548px;  /*  PX!! */
```

Then add the doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
   #gallery
    {
      width:750px;
      height:548px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery">
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition of height and width should be in pixels, em's or percentages, e.g:

```
width: 750px;
height: 548px;
```

Comment: I prefer furlongs, personally.

Comment: Angstroms are far more precise.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for pointing the error! Just found it myself after discovering the CSS Validator. I was deceived by the fact that it worked without DOCTYPE, and even with DOCTYPE without the second line ("http:// etc.).
PS. Next time I try Swedish inches (2.96 cm).